# User's Profile based record types selection in Visualforce Page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have custom visualforce page for record type selection (custom button on custom object to create a new record - when user clicks on the button, it will navigate to record type selection page) 
Record type selection page is showing all record types irrespective of user's profile visibility at record type level. 
I would like to control / display only record types based on Users Profile i.e. if there are 3 record types available on custom object, based on users login profile, has to see record types (for example 2 record types only) 
Note:  wrote 'with sharing apex controller' - it is not working as expected.

Below is my code (Apex Controller)

```
public with sharing class  recTypeSelInterventions {

  public recTypeSelInterventions (ApexPages.StandardSetController controller)   
   {
 public list<RecordType> getRecordTypes()
   {
     RecordTypes = [select Id, Name, Description, IsActive from RecordType where sObjectType='Interventions__c' and IsActive!=False ORDER by Name];
     return RecordTypes;

   }

/************getselop method displays record type picklist values ******************/  
   public List<selectOption> getselop()
     {
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();

     Schema.DescribeSObjectResult d = Schema.SObjectType.Interventions__c; 
     Map<Id,Schema.RecordTypeInfo> rtMapById = d.getRecordTypeInfosById();

      for(id rtId: rtMapById.keyset())
       {
            if(rtMapById.get(rtId).getName() != 'Master')
             {
                options.add(new selectoption(rtId,rtMapById.get(rtId).getName()));   
                mapRTIdAndName.put(rtId,rtMapById.get(rtId).getName()); 
                mapRTNameAndId.put(rtMapById.get(rtId).getName(),rtId);         
              }            
       }        
        return options;
   }
```

Visualforce Page:

```
<apex:page standardController="customObj__c" extensions="recTypeSelInterventions" recordSetvar="Interventions" >
<apex:sectionHeader subtitle="Select Intervention Record Type" title="New Intervention"  />
<apex:outputLabel >Select a record type for the new intervention. To skip this page in the future, change your record type settings 
                   on your personal setup page.
</apex:outputLabel>
<br/><br/>  
<apex:messages />


    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageblock title="Select Record Type">
            <apex:pageBlockSection >
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                    <apex:outputLabel > Record Type of new record </apex:outputLabel>
                    <apex:selectList value="{!selected}" size="1" required="true">
                        <apex:selectOptions value="{!selop}">
                        </apex:selectOptions>
                    </apex:selectList>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageblockButtons location="bottom" >
               <apex:commandButton value="Continue" action="{!Continuous}"/>
                <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}"/>
            </apex:pageblockButtons>
        </apex:pageblock>

        <apex:outputLabel value="Available Intervention Record Types" style="font-weight:bold" />
        <br/><br/> 
            <apex:dataTable value="{!RecordTypes}" var="RecordType" columns="2" Border="1" cellpadding="1" >
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">Record Type Name</apex:facet>
                    <apex:outputText value="{!RecordType.Name}" style="font-weight:bold"> </apex:outputText>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">Description</apex:facet>
                    <apex:outputText value="{!RecordType.Description}"> </apex:outputText>
                </apex:column>
   </apex:dataTable>

    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Thanks in advantage for any advice.

Comment: It would help attract more answers if you shared the relevant parts of your code (VF and Page) with us here.

Comment: public with sharing class  recTypeSelInterventions {

Comment: public list<RecordType> getRecordTypes()  {     RecordTypes = [select Id, Name, Description, IsActive from RecordType where sObjectType='Interventions__c' and IsActive!=False ORDER by Name];
     return RecordTypes;       }   public List<selectOption> getselop()
     {        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();        
     Schema.DescribeSObjectResult d =Schema.SObjectType.Interventions__c; 
     Map<Id,Schema.RecordTypeInfo> rtMapById = d.getRecordTypeInfosById();      for(id rtId: rtMapById.keyset())       {

Comment: if(rtMapById.get(rtId).getName() != 'Master')             {                options.add(new selectoption(rtId,rtMapById.get(rtId).getName()));   
                mapRTIdAndName.put(rtId,rtMapById.get(rtId).getName()); 
                mapRTNameAndId.put(rtMapById.get(rtId).getName(),rtId);

Comment: <apex:form >
        <apex:pageblock title="Select Record Type">
            <apex:pageBlockSection >
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                    <apex:outputLabel > Record Type of new record </apex:outputLabel>
                    <apex:selectList value="{!selected}" size="1" required="true">
                        <apex:selectOptions value="{!selop}">
                        </apex:selectOptions>
                    </apex:selectList>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>

Comment: <apex:outputLabel value="Available Intervention Record Types" style="font-weight:bold" />
        <br/><br/> 
            <apex:dataTable value="{!RecordTypes}" var="RecordType" columns="2" Border="1" cellpadding="1" >
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">Record Type Name</apex:facet>
                    <apex:outputText value="{!RecordType.Name}" style="font-weight:bold"> </apex:outputText>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column >

Comment: My apologies. Please check now

Comment: i think the answer you are looking for is here: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/5065/2602

Comment: @KiranKulakarni You can edit your post at any time by clicking on the `Edit` link at the bottom left of your question. When you post code, after pasting it into your post, select it and click on the `{}` pre-formatted text icon so that it's legible to anyone who reads it. Don't expect others to do this for you by posting your code in comments.

Comment: Have you looked at Quick Create Actions instead of buttons for this? You can create an action for each record type that's limited to users by profile. The action they can use should only appear on the current page if their profile has access to it. That would seem to solve your problem.