# User able to create Account record, even though its profile has no 'create' Account object permission

Tags: apex, unit-test, bug

I have the user `user1` assigned to the profile `profileA`.

Profile `profileA` does not have **create** object permission on *Account*.

Inside text context, with `Sytem.runas()` method, I am able to make `user1` create an *Account*.

But, if I try to create the Account using Workbench, I receive the expected error due the profile does not have create permission.

So, why it is possible to create under text context? would it be a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System method runAs enables you to write test methods that change the user context to an existing user or a new user so that the user’s **record sharing** is enforced. The runAs method **doesn’t enforce user permissions or field-level permissions, only record sharing.**

Giving permission on object in profile comes under object sharing and runAs only consider record sharing.

**Example Code:**

```
@isTest 
private class testSEClass{

    private static testmethod void testSEClass(){

        List<User> users = new List<User>();
        Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name like :'%' + 'std user clone' + '%' Limit 1];

        for (Integer k = 0; k < 50; k++) {

            users.add(new User(Alias = 'standt', Email = 'standarduser@testorg.com', 
                EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8', LastName = 'Testing', LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US', 
                LocaleSidKey = 'en_US', ProfileId = p.Id, TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles', 
                UserName = 'standarduser' + Math.random() + '@testorg.com'));
        }
        insert users;
        System.runAs(users[0]) {
            //This debug statement returns False.
            System.debug(Account.sObjectType.getDescribe().isAccessible());
            Account a = new Account(name='abcdsss');
            insert a;
            //It successfully inserts account record.
            System.debug(a.id);

        }

    }
}
```

I tried this code in with sharing mode as well, i got same results. You can externally apply [DML checks](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_perms_enforcing.htm) to check whether any user has object and field level permissions or not.

[Resource](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_tools_runas.htm)

Comment: So, would not be possible at all to test if some profiles can or cannot create certain records?

Comment: @LeandroFerreiraFernandes Check my updated answer. You can apply DML checks to check if user has object and field level access or not.

Comment: Good point! Although we can test permission level on **object** and **field**, Salesforce still lacks a way to test permission on **record** level.

For example, when a profile attempts to create a record of a specific recordType which is not assigned to it. Even if the profile has object permission, the DML will fail.

Comment: @LeandroFerreiraFernandes For this you can check what record types are available to given user. [Finding if which users have a record type available to them](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/5065/20721)