# (Schema.SObjectType) || Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void

Tags: apex, record-type, sobject, schema, sobjecttype

I'm trying to list the Record Types that a user has access to. Unfortunately, this cannot be done through SOQL Query (IIRC) and the only choice I have would be to either use Schema.SObjectType (Apex) or Metadata API.

I have found a Source Code which adds this method:

```
// Returns a List of the Names of all RecordTypes
// available to the running user for a given SOBject type
public static List<String> GetAvailableRecordTypeNamesForSObject(
    Schema.SObjectType objType
) {
    List<String> names = new List<String>();
    List<RecordTypeInfo> infos = objType.getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfos();
    // If there are 2 or more RecordTypes...
    if (infos.size() > 1) {
        for (RecordTypeInfo i : infos) {
            if (i.isAvailable() 
                // Ignore the Master Record Type, whose Id always ends with 'AAA'.
                // We check the Id because Name can change depending on the user's language.
                && !String.valueOf(i.getRecordTypeId()).endsWith('AAA'))
                names.add(i.getName());
        }
    } 
    // Otherwise there's just the Master record type,
    // so add it in, since it MUST always be available
    else names.add(infos[0].getName());
    return names;
}
```

And can be run through Anonymous Apex using this block:

```
List <String> availableRecordTypes = GetAvailableRecordTypeNamesForSObject(Case.SObjectType);
System.debug(availableRecordTypes);
```

However, I'm getting this error.

```
Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void GetAvailableRecordTypeNamesForSObject(Schema.SObjectType) from the type anon
```

Can you help me correct the Source Code above? Thank you.

Source: here ([Finding if which users have a record type available to them using SOQL](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5063/finding-if-which-users-have-a-record-type-available-to-them-using-soql))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used a static method. So it must added inside a Class like this.

```
public without sharing class SystemUtils {


    public static List<String> GetAvailableRecordTypeNamesForSObject(
            Schema.SObjectType objType
    ) {
        List<String> names = new List<String>();
        List<RecordTypeInfo> infos = objType.getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfos();
        // If there are 2 or more RecordTypes...
        if (infos.size() > 1) {
            for (RecordTypeInfo i : infos) {
                if (i.isAvailable()
                        // Ignore the Master Record Type, whose Id always ends with 'AAA'.
                        // We check the Id because Name can change depending on the user's language.
                        && !String.valueOf(i.getRecordTypeId()).endsWith('AAA'))
                    names.add(i.getName());
            }
        }
        // Otherwise there's just the Master record type,
        // so add it in, since it MUST always be available
        else names.add(infos[0].getName());
        return names;
    }

}
```

You need class.staticmethod name to call a static method, if it is being called outside that class.

```
SystemUtils.GetAvailableRecordTypeNamesForSObject(Case.SObjectType);
```

If both method and caller has been written in Anonymous apex, only then calling it without a class like this `GetAvailableRecordTypeNamesForSObject(Case.SObjectType);` would work.

Comment: Hi @Nagendra

Thank you very much! Invoking the Class name before the method worked for me!
Appreciate the help! 

I have upvoted your answer, though since I'm new here, my vote seemed to have not displayed.

Comment: @Yvan-NewbieDeveloper You can accept the answer instead.

Comment: Hi @Nagendra 

Yup - did that now. Thanks again!