# How to get the Available Record Types by Profile for a STANDARD Object

Tags: profile, permissions, record-type, standard-objects, workbench

I found this post (especially Adam Torman's comment) really helpful in getting to the most elusive element of a profile--which record types are assigned to it for creation:
[Available Record Type by Profiles](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4377/available-record-type-by-profiles)

However, when I did a "Retrieve" in Workbench with a package.xml with * on CustomObject and * on Profile, I only got the permissions for recordtypes on Custom Objects, not standard objects like Account and Case (where I really need it).  I know this sounds obvious because the metadata element literally says "CustomObject", but when I look at my package.xml I pull down in MavensMate, Account and Case ARE listed in there.  And there certainly doesn't seem to be a metadata type for StandardObject.

Does anybody know how to pull this down in a similar way?  We have thousands of record types and hundreds of profiles (bad I know--this is part of an effort to clean them up).  We've written a python script that reads through the XML and compiles it into a nice excel file, but the missing link is all of the record type profile permissions on standard objects, which are of course the most important.

Comment: Here's the package.xml I have been using:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomObject</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Profile</name>
    </types>
    <version>26.0</version>
</Package>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Standard objects aren't retrieved using the CustomObject wild card syntax. You must specifically reference each standard object you want to retrieve.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
<types>
    <members>Account</members>
    <name>CustomObject</name>
</types>
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>Profile</name>
</types>
<version>26.0</version>
</Package>
```

Comment: Thanks!  Apparently you can also mix and match as well.  So this gives me account PLUS all the custom objects:
<members>Account</members>
<members>*</members>

Comment: @PatrickWatkins You're exactly right. You can also list custom objects by name instead of grabbing all of them.