# Can we Update Cloned Profile automatically If any changes happen in original profile

Tags: apex, trigger, administration

1. I created a profile, and clone that profile and created another two new profile.
2. If i change any changes in that profile I want to reflect those changes in cloned profiles.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible as there is no link between the 2 profiles. Another option for you is to use a permission set and make changes to it. You can assign that permission set to the users belonging to those profiles. That way you will only have to make change in one permission set.

Answer (score 1):

I want to elaborate RajeshShah's answer.

Profiles generally created for large number of users which shares the common privileges.Then for particular set of users which require additional permissions you can create permission set.That means permission sets are used to enhance the privileges.

In your case when you created first profile you should keep the minimum privileges which will be in common.

Then beside cloning that profile you can simply enhance the privileges by permission set.

For more information see this [example](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008rqQIAQ)

It is not possible to write triggers on Profile or permission set so i don't think reflecting the changes is possible from some simple solution.

Meanwhile here is a nice thread which focus on [comparing and managing profile](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/499/can-i-compare-profiles?rq=1)